# Outlook API - Getting Webhook Notifications With Data

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-api

I've configured Outlook Webhook notifications according to the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks). And I now receive notifications when an email arrives to Outlook inbox.

[image]

I don't see any data regarding the E-Mail that was received.

For example, I expected the `ResourceData` to contain the senders mail, subject, etc.

What should I do to resolve the E-Mail metadata in the hook response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ResourceData contains the Id property. Just use it to get the message.